# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string (load data from csv into mysql using pyhton)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

i try to load the data from csv file into mysql database by using python script. when i run the code i got the error about the string.

error : TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

```
df = pd.read_csv('testing.csv', delimiter=';', skiprows = 4)
print(df)

for row in df:

 cursor.execute('INSERT INTO FIRMS(ID, \
                REGISTRATION_NUMBER, NAME, DATE_ESTABLISHED, ADDRESS, PHONE_NO, FAX_NO, EMAIL, STATUS, POSTAL_CODE, DISTRICT, STATE )'\
                     'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")',
                     row)

df.to_pymysql("FIRMS", db , flavor='pymysql', if_exists='append')
db.commit()
cursor.commit()
```

any suggestion to solve this issue? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What is `len(row)` and does it match the number of `%s` in your INSERT statement?

Comment: yes it match with the number of %s in INSERT statement.. based on my understanding, the %s refer to the number of columns in the firms table.. i'm actually newbie in python and mysql

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're trying to pass a list where it wants a tuple. This should be fixable by casting row to a tuple like so:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO FIRMS(ID, \
            REGISTRATION_NUMBER, NAME, DATE_ESTABLISHED, ADDRESS, PHONE_NO, FAX_NO, EMAIL, STATUS, POSTAL_CODE, DISTRICT, STATE )'\
                 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")',

                tuple(row))
```

That should fix it up for you

Comment: i tried the suggestion but still got an error which is : TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting